# How to define Laravel relationship when multiple columns are associated

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have models just like I have mentioned below,
How laravel eloquent-relationship can be implemented on it?

**User Model**

```
id
name
```

**Post Model**

```
id
title
desc
created_by = foreign key on User->id
```

**Stage One (PostStageOneModel)**

```
id
post_id
assigned_by
assigned_to
```

**Stage Two (PostStageTwoModel)**

```
post_id
assigned_by  = foreign key on User->id
assigned_to  = foreign key on User->id
```

**Stage Three (PostStageThreeModel)**

```
post_id
assigned_by  = foreign key on User->id
assigned_to  = foreign key on User->id
```

**Stage Four (PostStageFourModel)**

```
post_id
assigned_by  = foreign key on User->id
assigned_to  = foreign key on User->id
```

**Stage Five (PostStageFiveModel)**

```
post_id
assigned_by  = foreign key on User->id
assigned_to  = foreign key on User->id
```

**Stage Six (PostStageSixModel)**

```
post_id
assigned_by  = foreign key on User->id
assigned_to  = foreign key on User->id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by defining following relations

**In PostStageOneModel  model**

```
public function assignedPost() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class, 'post_id', 'post_id');
}

public function assigner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'assigned_by', 'id');
}

public function assignee()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'assigned_to', 'id');
}
```

**In Post Model**

```
public function identifiedBy() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'identified_by', 'id');
}

public function postAssignedBy() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(User::class, PostStageOneModel::class, 'post_id', 'id', 'post_id', 'assigned_by' );
}

public function postAssignedTo() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(User::class, PostStageOneModel::class, 'post_id', 'id', 'post_id', 'assigned_to' );
}
```

**In User Model**

```
public function assigned()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PostStageOneModel::class, 'assigned_by', 'id');
}

public function assignedTo()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PostStageOneModel::class, 'assigned_to', 'id');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Relationships can specify which column they use:

```
public function assigner(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'assigned_by');
}
public function assignee(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'assigned_to');
}
```

Comment: Hello Jeff, thank you so much for your effort, For assigner, I am getting correct result, but for assignee, I am getting null!

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Please look at my answer and let me know, if I can improve anything on that.

Answer (score 1):

User model should have an `hasMany` relationship type like below:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class User extends Model {
    //...
    public function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

Posts belongs to Users via created_by attribute

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Post extends Model {
    //...
    public function createdBy() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'created_by');
    }
}
```

PostStageOneModel belongs to posts and to users using 2 different attributes

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class PostStageOneModel extends Model {
    //...
    public function post() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }
    public function assignedTo() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'assigned_to');
    }
    public function assignedBy() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'assigned_by');
    }
}
```

hope this help

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Please look at my answer and let me know, if I can improve anything on that.

Comment: Sounds correct

   `  return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'assigned_by', 'id');`

in case of relations with users you can omit 'id' (which is default)

Comment: I have intentionally mentioned everything, so that it will look more understandable to everyone who will use it in future. Thank you.